# How do I use quantifiers to specify a pair of elements?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I'm just learning about quantifiers in class, and my professor has so far only given us examples where he uses quantifiers to specify one element/variable at a time from a set.

So he would write something like: $\forall$ a $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ ...

Am I limited to only defining one variable at a time? Would it be "legal" for me to write $\forall$ (a, b) $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It's incorrect to write $\forall (a,b)\in \Bbb R$. In principle you should write $\forall a\in \Bbb R\forall b\in \Bbb R$, but it's common to **abbreviate** this as $\forall a,b\in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, you would want to write $$\forall a\in\Bbb R\forall b\in\Bbb R(\ldots)$$

But it is perfectly readable to write $\forall a,b\in\Bbb R\ldots$

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can also write $\forall (a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, but this hardly saves over the other answers.